# Trigger is not fired for all rows in case of update(random)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have created a single trigger to catch all insert, update and delete operations in a replica table but in case of update, two rows are inserted one with before update values and another row with after update values but it is not working as expected.

I have tried all possible ways to do it. Now, I want to know whether I should use transaction at trigger level for update operation or should try something else.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsertUpdateDelete_xyz] ON [dbo].[xyz] 
FOR UPDATE,INSERT, DELETE
AS
declare @accountID int;
declare @billingDate date;
declare @amount decimal(18, 2);

---- Get data from inserted/ updated
select @accountID = i.AccountID from inserted i;    
select @billingDate=i.BillingDate from inserted i;  
select @amount=i.Amount from inserted i;

-- Insert Case
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) 
BEGIN
    insert into xyz_Audit
    (AccountID, BillingDate, Amount, Audit_Action) 
    values(@accountID,@billingDate,@amount,'INSERT');
END

-- Update Case
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO xyz_Audit
    (AccountID, BillingDate, Amount, Audit_Action)
    SELECT d.AccountID, d.BillingDate, d.Amount,             
            'BeforeUpdate'  FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID

    INSERT INTO xyz_Audit
    (AccountID, BillingDate, Amount,Audit_Action) 

         values(@accountID,@billingDate,@amount,'AfterUpdate');
END


-- Delete Case
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM deleted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO xyz_Audit
    (AccountID, BillingDate, Amount, Audit_Action) 
    select accountID,billingDate,amount, 'DELETE'
    from deleted
END
```

[image: Image showing data saved in replica table]

I expected that if 9 records are updated then there should be before and after update values for all rows but sometimes it skips. As you can see for Inst.8 there should be before and after rows but it has captured only before row and then insert but in actual there was no row deleted and inserted, only updation was done. Sometime out of 9, it pick only before rows not after update rows or sometime 2 or 3 after update rows not before update rows.

Answer (score 2):

your trigger assuming that only one row will be affected for insert / update / delete operatons. Which means the `inserted` or `deleted` may contains multiple rows

and the following part does not handle that.

```
---- Get data from inserted/ updated
select @accountID = i.AccountID from inserted i;    
select @billingDate=i.BillingDate from inserted i;  
select @amount=i.Amount from inserted i;
```

Actually you don't required the above at all. You should just insert into the `Audit` table directly from the `inserted` or `deleted` table

For example the `"INSERT CASE"` should be

```
-- Insert Case
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) 
BEGIN
    insert into xyz_Audit (AccountID, BillingDate, Amount, Audit_Action) 
    select AccountID, BillingDate, Amount, Audit_Action= 'INSERT'
    from   inserted;
END
```

similarly you need to change accordingly for the Update section. And you are already doing it correctly for the delete section

Comment: Okk thanks for the reply. R u 100% sure that this is the only problem. now whenever 9 or 18 rows will come for update, it will capture before and after rows for all of them. because sometime it work in appropriate manner and sometime not @squirrel

Comment: one more thing, second update portion of trigger require transaction or not ? will it insert data in sequence or in random manner? means Inst. 1 having before and after rows simultaneously or in some random manner

Comment: it will in the sequence of your insert statement

Comment: thank you @squirrel definitely will Accept it as answer if no fault happen in data capturing after trying for some time. Very big thank to u